# how to add third party (.)framework as dependency for React native native module in Xcode

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

We have a SDK which depends on Alamofire and Private framework to function. Now we are trying to build a wrapper over the SDK for react native. We created native module code and added Alamofire as dependency for it through Podspec. Our private framework is not hosted anywhere. Now we want to add this private framework to react native native module as dependency. We tried adding to react native project/iOS part, but react native project complaints while building the native module about pvt_framework_headers.h not found. Private framework is added and embedded correctly. How to add external dependencies to react native module?

Podspec file:

```
  s.dependency "React"
  # ...
  # s.dependency "..."
  s.dependency 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
  s.dependency 'SwiftyJSON'
  s.dependency 'SVProgressHUD'
  s.dependency 'Alamofire'
  s.dependency 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
```

Any help or guidance highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you found the fix for this issue?

Comment: @bharathikumar and ltzdsp Have you resolved this issue? I stumbled on to this problem before I solved it myself. Check if this helps to resolve your issues. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64219898/how-to-add-a-thirdparty-sdk-multiple-framework-files-to-react-native-library/64332452#64332452