# How to add a thirdparty SDK (multiple .framework files) to react native library module?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, react-native-native-module, swift-framework

I have built a react native library module (with RN 0.63). This module depends on some thirdparty SDKs. When integrated with Android (using .aar files) it works just fine. In case of iOS, I have been able to get the library module working without the SDK (using swift hence with the bridging header). On adding the SDK, I am getting errors such as .h is not avaialble.

This is my directory My directory structure:

```
react-native-lib
--android
--ios
----MyCls.swift
----MyCls.m
----react-native-lib-Bridging-Header.h
----SDKS
------DEBUG
--------A.framework
--------B.framework
--------A-Debug.podspec
--------B-Debug.podspec
------THIRDPARTY
--------JSONModel.framework
--------CocoaLumberjack.framework
--------... other frameworks
--react-native-lib.podspec
--Example
--index.js
--Logger.swift
--package.json
```

I have a sample application in Swift which uses the SDKS folder, but I cannot seem to get RN to recognize the framework files/headers.
The last few lines of the Podspec file of react-native-lib is as follows:

```
  ...
  s.dependency "React"
  s.dependency 'JSONModel', '~> 1.8.0'
  s.dependency 'CocoaLumberjack', '~> 3.6.1'
```

My example application Podfile:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '11.0'
use_frameworks!

project 'example', {
    'Debug' => :debug,
    'Release' => :release,
}
#
def applibs
 pod 'A-Debug', :configuration => ['Debug'], :path  => '../node_modules/react-native-lib/ios/SDKS/DEBUG/A-Debug.podspec'
# ... A-Release, B-Debug, B-Release
# The release folders not shown in structure above.
end



target 'example' do
 config = use_native_modules!

 use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])
  
   applibs
  
  # Disabled Flipper because of use_frameworks!
  
end
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong and how I can overcome this issue. There seems to be not quite a lot of articles on how such 3rd party sdk can be integrated in a library module. I have explored similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62206814/how-to-add-third-party-framework-as-dependency-for-react-native-native-module) one which is still unsolved and has insufficient information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

after days of research and experimenting, I have been able to resolve the problem. It's simple enough, made difficult with lack of resources on the topic.

Primarily, I used the podspec file in my react native lib (ios folder) to add dependency on the 3rd party frameworks as follows.

**react-native-lib.podspec**

```
  s.dependency 'A-Debug', '~> 1.2.3', :configurations => :debug
  s.dependency 'B-Debug', '~> 2.3.4', :configurations => :debug
  s.dependency 'A-Release', '~> 1.2.3', :configurations => :release
  s.dependency 'B-Release', '~> 2.3.4', :configurations => :release
```

In my example application, the podfile works as shown above (by adding the pods in applibs). However, I encountered the 'enable bitcode' error where the compiler asked me to recompile the 3rd party libraries with bitcode enabled. I worked around it with the following post install script in the application (not library) podfile (obtained from [here](https://www.thetopsites.net/article/52646009.shtml)).

**Example/ios/Podfile**

```
  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
      end
    end
  end
```

Do a cache clean, and as an extra measure, clear node modules.
Then simply run the following in your application directory:

```
yarn install && cd ios && pod install && cd .. && yarn react-native start
```

Open your project in Xcode and import your SDK as per its documentation. Hope this saves you hours of research, experiment and debugging.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, been scratching my head over this for a while. So just to be clear, you ask your users to add the pods in applibs in their Podfiles correct? Do you think there's a better solution to make this work out of the box? Don't get me wrong, as helpful as your answer is, this seems like a hacky way around. Also, did you manage to get rid of the errors like .h file is not available?

Comment: @AfrazHussain that is what I thought as well, but it appeared to be the recommended way according to an article I read at that time. Plus it was the only way I got it to work. However, if you're looking to find another solution, take a look at this implementation: https://github.com/MCROEngineering/react-native-onfido-sdk .

Comment: @AfrazHussain regarding getting errors like .h file not available, the steps in the answer did help me to remove them. Are you having issues with the bridging header and the corresponding .m file?

Comment: @sbsatter Hi I have some doubt creating a native modules. Could you please help me? Is there any way I can contact you via mail ?